# regex to convert string 018v-s001v => 18v-s1v but 020v_001 => 20v_001

Tags: php, regex

I'm struggling with a Regex to convert the following strings

```
018v-s001v => 18v-s1v
018v-s001r => 18v-s1r
018r-s002v => 18r-s2v
020v_001 => 20v_001
020r_002 => 20r_002
0001 => 0001
```

I could manage to convert the first three cases but I'm struggling with the latter three: How to preserve the zeros after`_` and the all zeros in the last case?

My attempt: `(0*)([1-9]{0,4}[vr]?)((-s)?+([0]{0,2}))?+([1-9][vr])?`

https://regex101.com/r/2go5KO/1

Comment: _Convert_ to what???

Comment: "018v-s001v" convert to "18v-s1v" etc.

Comment: Why is the `0001` an exception? What's the rule behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your given examples, you could use

```
000\d+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=\b|[a-z])0+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/t2txGj/1/).

Comment: plz add some explanation. Actually How SKIP and FAIL works here ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the expected result for your example data you might use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

You could match one or more times a zero `0+`, capture in a group one or more digits and use a character class to match by v or r `([0-9]+[vr])`

**Regex**

[`0+([0-9]+[vr])`](https://regex101.com/r/E03uio/1)

**Replace**

Captured group 1 `$1`

[Demo Php](https://3v4l.org/Eeh4p)

Answer (score -1):

How about this one:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?:(\d{4})|(0)?(\d{2}\w))(?:([-_])(?:(\d{3})|(\w)(0+)(\d+?\w)))?/m', 
'$1$3$4$5$6$8', $subject);
```

This produces all the results you require from your test strings. But it wasn't clear where a zero definitely will appear or only optionally. But I'm sure it can be adapted. Also I noticed the separator was occasionally a hyphen - and occasionally an underscore _ and it wasn't clear if that was just your typing or was significant. In any case I've assumed it could be either somewhat randomly.