# regex to convert 010v-s001v to 10v-s1v

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a Regex that removes the leading zeros at the beginning and after `-s` eg. converts `010v-s001v` to `10v-s1v`.

```
010v-s001v => 10v-s1v
0100v-s001v => 100v-s1v
018v-s001v => 18v-s1v
018v-s001r => 18v-s1r
018r-s002v => 18r-s2v
020v_001 => 20v_001
```

My attempt: `(0*)([1-9]{0,4}[vr]?)((-s)?+([0]{0,2}))?+([1-9][vr])?`

But this adds `-s00` to the string: 10v-s001v => 10v-s00-s1v

https://regex101.com/r/2go5KO/2

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Don't you think it's time to learn regular expressions? See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216440/regex-to-convert-kbt-y102-9999-0001v-s001v-n1v-s1v), [**this one of your's**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331373/regex-to-substitute-leading-4-or-3-zeros-under-certain-circumstances) and [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237417/regex-to-convert-string-018v-s001v-18v-s1v-but-020v-001-20v-001), just to name a few.

Comment: You have asked many questions similar to this one before. Most of the  answers you got have a deep breakdown of regex. If you read them you will get the most basic patterns out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to think about this differently, we've got two cases here:

- leading zeros
- zeros after `-s`

So we create a regex for both of them and use `|` to separate them:

```
^0+|(-s)0+
```

And replace with `$1`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2go5KO/3)

If your regex engine supports look behinds, you can do this:

```
^0+|(?<=-s)0+
```

and replace with empty string.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2go5KO/4)

Answer (score -2):

Regex:`0+([1-9][\w]*)(?:(\-s)0+(\d+[A-Za-z]*))*`

Replace with:`\1\2\3`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OASgnt/1)